# How to read last updated hand-wash data from healthkit framework?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I use below code to fetch hand wash data from healthkit. I used below query/sample data query to retrieve last updated hand-wash data but return nil.

```
func readMostRecentSample(for type: HKSampleType, completion: @escaping (HKQuantitySample?, Error?) -> Void) {
            print("read query function calling")
            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date.distantPast, end: Date(), options: .strictEndDate)
            let mostRecentSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
            let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: type, predicate: predicate, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: [mostRecentSortDescriptor]) { (query, result, error) in
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard let samples = result as? [HKQuantitySample], let sample = samples.first else {
                        completion(nil, error)
                        print("HKit error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
    
                        return
                    }
                    completion(sample, nil)
                    print("read HKsample :: \(sample.quantity)")
                    print("read HKsample :: \(sample.quantityType)")
    
                }
            }
            print("read query end calling")
    
            healthStore.execute(sampleQuery)
        }    

    HealthKitDataStore.sharedInstance.readMostRecentSample(for: handWashCount) { (sample, error) in
                    
                    print("hand_washError \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

                
                print("hand_washsampledata \(sample.debugDescription)")
                if let sample = sample{
                    
                    self.patientVital.hand_wash = "\(sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.init(from: "count/day")))"
                    print("hand_wash\(sample.count)")
                    print("hand_wash\(sample.quantity.is(compatibleWith: HKUnit.init(from: "count/day")))")
                    print("hand_wash\(sample.quantity.is(compatibleWith: HKUnit.init(from: "count/day")))")
    
                    print("hand_wash: \(self.patientVital.pulsebpm ?? "no data")")
                }
            }
```

no data received.
Please provide some insight on this...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is so late, but posting this might help others who is seeking solution for the same.

Hand Washing event is instance of `HKCategory` so samples are object of `HKCategorySample`. But you are trying to get as `HKQuantitySample`.

Here what I have tried and it is working as expected.

```
public struct HealthDataManager {
    private let healthStore: HKHealthStore

    public static let shared = HealthDataManager()

    public init() {
        healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    }

    public func readRecentHandWash(for date: Date, completion: @escaping (HKSample?, Error?) -> Void) {
    
        guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
            print("Healthkit is not available.")
            return
        }
    
        guard let handWash = HKCategoryType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.handwashingEvent) else {
            fatalError("*** Unable to get handwashingEvent on this device ***")
        }
    
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: [handWash]) { (success, error) in
                        
            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date.distantPast, end: Date(), options: .strictEndDate)
            let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: handWash,
                                      predicate: predicate,
                                      limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
                                      sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)]) { (query, samples, error) in
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    if let err = error {
                        completion(nil, err)
                    } else {
                        guard let actualSamples = samples else {
                            completion(nil, error) // Here you will not get any error, but you have no data, so you have to pass custom error object that shows no data found.
                            return
                        }
                        
                        completion(actualSamples.first, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            healthStore.execute(query)
        }
    }
}
```

And this when you supposed to call this method :

```
HealthDataManager.shared.readRecentHandWash(for: Date()) { (sample, error) in
        
    var str = ""
        
    if let washSample = sample as? HKCategorySample {
                                
        str = str.appendingFormat("\n\(washSample.categoryType)")
        let diffComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute, .second], from: washSample.startDate, to: washSample.endDate)
        let minutes = diffComponents.minute
        let seconds = diffComponents.second

        if let mins = minutes, mins > 0 {
            str = str + " : " + "\(mins)" + " min"
            if let secs = seconds, secs > 0 {
                str = str + " " + "\(secs)" + " secs"
            }
        } else if let secs = seconds, secs > 0 {
            str = str + " : " + "\(secs)" + " secs"
        }
            
        print("Most Recent : ", str)
    }
}
```